# Creating subplots with filtered y values

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression, subplot

I have a plot that looks like this:

[image]

And I want to create subplots with linear regressions on the y axis values from 0-5, 5-10, and 10-15 days.
My code currently looks like this:

```
#Read in proper dataframe
storms = pd.read_csv('storms.csv', sep = ',', header = 0, ) 

#Define variables for linear regression - frequency
x_col ='season'
y_col = 'days'
x = storms[x_col]
y = storms[y_col]
x_array = np.array(x).reshape(-1,1)
y_array = np.array(y).reshape(-1,1)

linreg = LinearRegression().fit(x_array,y_array)

#Perform linear regression for frequency 
lin_reg(x_array,y_array)

#Plot
sns.set_theme(context='notebook', style='darkgrid')
sns.light_palette("#79C")

plt.scatter(x_array,y_array, alpha = 0.25,)
plt.plot(x_array,linreg.predict(x_array),  label='y=-0.0154x+38.5978')
plt.xlabel('Season')
plt.ylabel('Duration of Storms (in days)')
plt.title('Duration of Storms Over Time')
plt.legend()
plt.show
```

I tried defining functions to filter the y axis values which I then applied with the plt.subplot function which looked like this:

```
def Filter1(f):
    if f <= 5:
        return False
    else:
        return True

y_filtered = Filter1(y_array)

#Plotting subplots
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(x_array,y_filtered)
```

But no success yet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking your x- and y-values from the dataframe columns, you can convert them to numpy arrays by calling

```
x = storms[x_col].values
y = storms[y_col].values
```

Then, you don't have to define any function to filter the values, you can just do it with numpy features. You can obtain an array containing `true` and `false` values depending on your condition. For example, you can say `x > 5` and it will give you an array with the same size as `x`, where for each original index in x there will be a `false` if the value at that index is below (or equal to) 5 and `true` if it is above 5.Then you can use that boolean array as a mask for other arrays of the same size, returning only the elements at the index where the mask is `true`. That's how you can filter with numpy:

```
mask = y[(y>=5) & (y<10)]
y_filtered = y[mask]
x_filtered = x[mask]
```

Then perform the regression with `x_filtered` and `y_filtered`.

Comment: Using the .values method you described, I get this error: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead...then it says to reshape as I had previously done